# OHLC anomalies on Yahoo Finance's data

Tags: cryptocurrency, historical-data, yahoo-finance, online-data-source

While looking at [BTC-USD data on Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD/), I was puzzled by the following:

```
Date            Open        High        Low         Close*      Adj Close** Volume
Apr 06, 2017    1,129.87    1,201.55    1,130.51    1,188.70    1,188.70    108,182,158
```

---

Note that Open = 1,129.87 < 1,130.51 = Low. How is this possible?

I thought that `Low` was the daily minimum and `High` was the daily maximum. Isn't that the case?

I found other [OHLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-high-low-close_chart) anomalies on other dates. April 6, 2017 is not the only anomalous date.

---

<sub>Yahoo Finance also has trouble with daylight savings time. It is assumed that the starting and ending dates are universal.</sub>

Comment: Yahoo Finance is known  for providing bad data.  Your quote is evidence of that.

Comment: And if you take a look at the chart the values from the historical data for the 6th match the chart for the 5th. Still has the wrong info.